# Visual C++: генерация случайных чисел (rand)

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Каким образом генерировать числа из промежутка от 256 до 2048 с шагом 64?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
int n = (rand() % 28 + 4) * 64;
```

Comment: спасибо! Все верно и коротко!

Comment: Только, если включая 2048, то не 28, а 29.

Answer (score 4):

Наверно так, в функции генерируется число и выводится, а в главной функции генерирует 100 чисел для проверки.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

size_t generateRandNumber()
{
    size_t randNumber = (((rand() % 28) + 4) * 64);
    std::cout << "Rand x64 number: " << randNumber << "\n";
    return randNumber;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        size_t number = generateRandNumber();
        if (number < 256 || number > 2048 || (number % 64) != 0)
        {
            std::cout << "Generate error number!\n";
        }
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

хах пока писал уже 3 ответа есть )

Comment: большое спасибо за помощь! Ничего страшного))

Comment: ну ка покажи в чём же она ложная? у меня всё отлично она робит.

Comment: кому вопрос?

Comment: ой, сорри что удалил комент, ложь в смысле никогда не выведется "Generate error number!\n" но я не увидел что number реально может быть < 256, а все остальное фигня, т.е. этому number > 2048 или этому (number % 64) != 0 небывать

Comment: Вобщем я сильно сильно сегодня туплю, я только что понял почему 28))) и все таки проверка ваша - гадость ;)

Comment: @peleshqqa мне, я тут жгу сегодня =)

Comment: Проверку я сделал для себя что бы убедится что генерируются нужные числа, первая проверка на то что число не меньше 256, вторая проверка что число будет не более 2048, а третья проверка на то что полученное число кратно 64. Измени формулу генерации чисел и увидишь что будет выводится то сообщение об ошибке.

Comment: Поясните мне дураку по-нормальному на будущее! Чтобы я чему-то научился!

int n = (rand() % 28 + 4) * 64;
вот этой строчкой я все сделал!
так вот где тут шаг,где диапазон и где что вообще и синтаксиис написанного!

Comment: @peleshqqa, если написать

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        cout << (rand() % 28 + 4) * 64 << '\n';

то будет выведено 10 случайных чисел, самое маленькое (может быть) 256, а самое большое 1984. (Если Вы хотите самое большое 2048, то вместо 28 используйте 29. rand() % n будет давать числа от 0 до n-1). И все эти числа кратны 64. 

Т.е. 64 это шаг, диапазон от 256 до 1984 (включительно). Количество шагов от 256 случайно.

--

А Вы что хотели?

Comment: Все верно! я то и хотел! просто мне необходимо уяснить синтаксис написанного здесь,чтобы в будушем не задавал глупых вопросов на форумах,а сам мог писать!

Comment: и к слову сказать,это здесь рандом с числами в десятичке, а если я буду работать с битами и cout, то мне придется переворачивать их прежде?

Comment: @peleshqqa, не совсем понял о битах и cout, но думаю, что в подобных вычислениях ничего переворачивать не надо.

Answer (score 2):

Как-то так:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <ctime> 
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
int main() 
{ 
    srand((unsigned)time(0)); 
    int random_integer; 
    int step = 64; //Шаг
    int lowest=256/step, highest=2048/step; //Левая правая граница.
    int range=(highest-lowest)+1;  
    for(int index=0; index<20; index++){ //Index - сколько чисел вам надо.
        random_integer = lowest+int(range*rand()/(RAND_MAX + 1.0)); 
        cout << random_integer*step << endl; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Решение подходит!

Answer (score 1):

Доброго времени суток! 
С использованием нового стандарта С++11x можно написать так:

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    size_t step = 64; // шаг
    size_t lowest=256/step, highest=2048/step; // левая и правая граница
    size_t n = 100; // требуемое количество чисел

    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis(lowest, highest);

    while(n--) {
        // генерация очередного числа
        int x = dis(gen)*64; 
        // проверка корректности генерации
        if(x < 256 || x > 2048) 
            std::cout << "Error: " << x << " outside of range" << std::endl;

    }
    return 0;
}
```